# MongoDB lookup with deeply nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a question where I don´t find the solution.

I have a collection "medium" with a deeply neested array in which a reference via ObjectID to a person collection.

**Medium Collection :**

```
{
    "title": "Test Medium",
        "mediumMetaData": {
        "metaData": [{
            "movietype": "movie",
            "year": 2019,
            "language": "german",
            "personInformation": {
                "actor": [{
                    "actors": "5e2c3b1daf0ba75b00415bb0"
                }],
                "director": [{
                    "directors": "5e2c3b1daf0ba75b00415bb0"
                }],
                "screenwriter": [{
                    "screenwriters": "5e2c3b1daf0ba75b00415bb0"
                }],
                "camera": [{
                    "cameras": "5e2c3b81af0ba75b00415bb1"
                }]
            }
        }]
    },
    "createdById": "5dcb108b59057b22702ecaa9"
}
```

**Person Collection** should match via "**_id**" field.

Now my problem. I want to build aggregate query with referencing to all objectIds in Person.

I tried several ways now but the lookup won´t match at all:

This is what I tried right now, but actor-tag is empty all the time:
First two stages are working, as I understood I need two unwinds, one for each array-part.

```
db.getCollection("medium").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e2c3d9002d512c71cda8006")
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$mediumMetaData.metaData", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$mediumMetaData.metaData.personInformation.actor", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "person", 
                "let" : {
                    "actor_id" : "$mediumMetaData.metaData.personInformation.actor.actors"
                }, 
                "pipeline" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "$expr" : [
                                {
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$_id", 
                                        "$$$actor_id"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "$project" : {
                            "_id" : 0.0
                        }
                    }
                ], 
                "as" : "actor1"
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Are these `"actors": "5e2c3b1daf0ba75b00415bb0"`/`"directors": "5e2c3b1daf0ba75b00415bb0"` strings or `ObjectId()`'s

Comment: Also as you're having `$match` as first stage on `ObjectId()`, You may not need `{ 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }`, cause your operation on medium collection will be on one doc, though it need to scan through all index keys of `Person`, Anyway first please try without it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
db.medium.aggregate([{ $match: { "_id": ObjectId("5e2df451d02e05b69467d1bc") } },
{ $unwind: '$mediumMetaData.metaData' },
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "Person",
        let: {
            actor: "$mediumMetaData.metaData.personInformation.actor", director: "$mediumMetaData.metaData.personInformation.director",
            screenwriter: "$mediumMetaData.metaData.personInformation.screenwriter", camera: "$mediumMetaData.metaData.personInformation.camera"
        },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $project: {
                    name: 1,
                    personID: {
                        $let:
                        {
                            vars: { id: '$_id' },
                            in: { $toString: "$$id" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $match:
                {
                    $expr:
                    {
                        $or:
                            [
                                { $in: ['$personID', "$$actor.actors"] },
                                { $in: ['$personID', "$$director.directors"] },
                                { $in: ['$personID', "$$screenwriter.screenwriters"] },
                                { $in: ['$personID', "$$camera.cameras"] }
                            ]
                    }
                }
            }, { $project: { personID: 0 } }
        ],
        as: "personInfo"
    }
}, { $unwind: { path: "$personInfo", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
{ $group: { _id: '$_id', 'metaData': { $addToSet: '$mediumMetaData.metaData' },
          personInfo: { $push: '$personInfo' }, title: { $first: '$title' }, createdById: { $first: '$createdById' } } },
{ $project: { 'mediumMetaData.metaData': '$metaData', createdById: 1, title: 1, personInfo: 1 } }
])
```

**Note :** If your  `"actors": "5e2c3b1daf0ba75b00415bb0"/"directors": "5e2c3b1daf0ba75b00415bb0"` are `ObjectId()`'s rather than `strings`, then you can avoid two `$project` stages in `pipeline` by just comparing something like `{ $in: ['$_id', "$$actor.actors"] }`

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bjkgBzR00Z7)